# Does every regular language have a linear grammar?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

**[Some definitions and facts (from Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar):**

1. A **linear grammar** is a context-free grammar that has at most one nonterminal in the right hand side of each of its productions.
2. the **left-linear** or **left regular grammars**, in which all nonterminals in right hand sides are at the left ends;
3. the **right-linear** or **right regular grammars**, in which all nonterminals in right hand sides are at the right ends.
4. Collectively, these two special types of linear grammars are known as the regular grammars; both can describe exactly the regular languages.

**Doubts**

1. Fourth fact used word "collectively" and then "both". What does it actually mean?

   - there is both right linear and left linear grammar for all regular languages
   - there is either right linear or left linear grammar for all regular languages
2. Can all non-linear regular grammars be converted into linear regular grammars? (Is there any systematic procedure for that?)

**Update**

I got it now how we can translate RLG to LLG and vice versa. So any given regular language has both RLG and LLG. Now the second question is remaining: Can all non-linear regular grammars be converted into linear regular grammars?

Comment: Right linear grammars have straight forward translation to and from DFA.   And may be left linear grammar for given regular language $L$ can be constructed from reversing right linear grammar of $L^R$.

Comment: Yeah I got it now that we can translate RLG to LLG. So any given regular language has both RLG and LLG. Now the second question is remaining: Can all non linear regular grammar be converted into a linear language?

Comment: Sorry but I think that regular grammars are by definition linear.

Comment: ohh indeed!!! I got confused because I read this: "language of non-linear grammar does not necessarily meant to be non-regular, because there may exist regular grammar for that language". Cant there be a non linear grammar for a regular language? If yes, can we convert it to right linear grammar (or left linear grammar)?

Comment: "Both" means "each of them", not "together". If you can think of a clearer way to put it, feel free to edit that page or suggest edits.

Comment: yeah I got that already as I said in comments and update. Now I am struggling with 2nd doubt. I read "language of non-linear grammar does not necessarily meant to be non-regular, because there may exist regular grammar for that language". Can there be a non linear grammar for a regular language? If yes, can we convert it to right linear grammar (or left linear grammar)?

Comment: 1) Yes, there can be a non linear grammar for a regular language, e.g. S- > SS | a. 2) No, there is no systematic method for converting every such grammar to a regular one: regularity of context-free languages is undecidable.

Comment: I have tried to improve the wording in Wikipedia. Please check if it is clear to you now.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the last question of the update.

The grammar $S \to aSb + 1$ is linear, but it generates the nonregular language $\{a^nb^n \mid n \geqslant 0\}$. Therefore, it cannot be converted into a regular linear grammar.

Comment: I was talking about converting non-linear grammar of regular language to linear grammar. Your language does not seem to be regular, but context free.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, but at the same time, if you start with a regular grammar, it generates a regular language and you can produce a regular linear grammar for this language.